# how to create this custom expandable list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
Widget? buildIcon(BuildContext context) {
return RotationTransition(
  turns: _iconTurns,
  child: !_isExpanded ? const Icon(Icons.add) : const Icon(Icons.minimize),);}



 Widget? _buildLeadingIcon(BuildContext context){
if (_effectiveAffinity(widget.controlAffinity)!=   ListTileControlAffinity.leading)
  return !_isExpanded
      ? RotationTransition(
          turns: _iconTurns,
          child: CircleAvatar(
              maxRadius: 14,
              backgroundColor: Const.buttonsColor.withOpacity(0.3),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Const.buttonsColor,
              )))
      : RotationTransition(
          turns: _iconTurns,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.minimize,
            color: Const.buttonsColor,
          ));
return buildIcon(context);
```

}

i want to create this expandable list tile in a flutter app.
I've customized `ExpansionTile` a little and changed the leading Widget.

Can somebody help me with this issue and show me some hint to add vertically dotted line for every item?

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i just added the code

Comment: Can you include full widget: [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and an output you are trying to archive?